# Does PdfReader implement Closeable?

Tags: itext

Does PdfReader, and the other itext classes which involve streams and/or have a close() method, implement the (auto)closeable interface?

In the API Doc I didn't find any reference saying that.

Just to know if I can use try with resources or not.

Comment: No, `PdfReader` doesn't implement `Closeable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bruno said, it doesn't implement Closeable...